# How to connect another machine to standalone h2o installation to create a cluster?

Tags: h2o

I want to try out H2O at home, on my commodity computers. How can I join them into the cluster?

Do I need to create a Hadoop cluster first?

Where can I find documentation, that could help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a Hadoop cluster is not needed. Here is the documentation [for starting nodes from the commandline](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turchin/3/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#%E2%80%A6%20From%20the%20Cmd%20Line-Cloud%20Formation%20Behavior). (I also found it useful to read the EC2 setup docs, and then browse through the EC2 scripts they supply.)

Basically you need to create a *flatfile*, which is a simple text file listing IP address and the port of each node in your cluster. You can give the cluster a name, and I like to name the flatfile with the same name, which will be "lantest.txt".

Then you need to get h2o.jar on each machine, and put your flatfile in the same directory (again, on each machine). Then start it on each machine with:

```
java -Xmx2G -ea -jar h2o.jar -name lantest -ip 192.168.x.y -port 54321 -flatfile lantest.txt
```

Keep that console window open, as log messages will be written to it.

Typically you change `.x.y` for each machine, but everything else stays the same. The `-Xmx2G` says I'm giving each machine 2GB; you might want to adjust that (but it must be exactly the same for every node.)

Something else that must be exactly the same is the version of h2o.jar: a minor version difference isn't good enough as it checks the md5 checksum!

The other thing you might struggle with is firewalls. Each node has to be able to see each other node on ports 54321 and 54322. So open those ports on the firewall on each machine. (On Windows, I also had to open access to Java.)

Comment: Great! Is there any added benefit of running more than one instance of h20 on a machine?

Comment: That is on my list of questions, too! I suspect if you have a 4GB machine and a 16GB machine, you could run 4x4GB instances on the big machine to have a 5-node cluster, but you'd be better just running a single instance on the 16GB machine, and not use a cluster (because of communication overhead). But if you have 10 of the 4GB machines, and two of the 16GB machines, setting up an 18-node 72GB cluster might be better than a 12-node 48GB cluster, or a 2-node 32GB cluster.  If you try any exotic combinations I'd be interested to hear the results.